# How to display/create a variable with a filtered dictionary item

Tags: python

I have a database with 8 entry lines. The dictionary was created using a .csv file created with Excel.

Here's what I am using to **try** to call on filtered items in `result`:

```
import csv
#Import a CSV with lines of relevant person's information to a dictionary
reader = csv.reader(open('NameGenderSport.csv'))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    if key in result:
        # implement your duplicate row handling here
        pass
    result[key] = row[1:]
print(result)

print(result.items())
parsedData = {k:v for k,v in result.items() if k == "Basketball"}
print(parsedData)
```

Here is the dictionary (`result`):

```
{'Peter': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Carlos': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Angela': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'David': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Kaitlin': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'Marco': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Andrew': ['Male', 'Golf'], 'Carmen': ['Female', 'Basketball']}
```

The desired output should only list the full information of the dictionary entry's that play Basketball:

```
Name: Peter 
Gender: Male
Sport: Basketball

Name: David 
Gender: Male
Sport: Basketball

Name: Carmen 
Gender: Female
Sport: Basketball
```

Any sort of direction would be amazingly helpful! Should I be using Classes? or some other methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.items()` gives `key, value` pairs, so in your dictionary comprehension `k` are keys (in this case, the people's names) and `v` are values (the lists of genders and sports). So the `if` needs to check if `Basketball` is in the values, as indicated by the previous answer. It will never be the case that `k == "Basketball"` because `k` are the people's names.

Since you know that your dictionary contains people's names as keys and other information as values, it will make for clearer code if you assign descriptive names like `name` and `info` when iterating over `result.items()`.

It looks like you want to get a string as output. You could use the following list comprehension with `join`.

```
result = {'Peter': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Carlos': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Angela': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'David': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Kaitlin': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'Marco': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Andrew': ['Male', 'Golf'], 'Carmen': ['Female', 'Basketball']}

parsedData = [
    '\n'.join([f"Name: {name}", f"Gender: {info[0]}", f"Sport: {info[1]}"])
    for name, info in result.items()
    if info[1] == "Basketball"
]
print('\n\n'.join(parsedData))
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Peter
Gender: Male
Sport: Basketball

Name: David
Gender: Male
Sport: Basketball

Name: Carmen
Gender: Female
Sport: Basketball
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

```py
result = {'Peter': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Carlos': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Angela': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'David': ['Male', 'Basketball'], 'Kaitlin': ['Female', 'Golf'], 'Marco': ['Male', 'Tennis'], 'Andrew': ['Male', 'Golf'], 'Carmen': ['Female', 'Basketball']}

print([(k,v) for k,v in result.items() if "Basketball" in v])
>> [('Peter', ['Male', 'Basketball']),
>>  ('David', ['Male', 'Basketball']),
>>  ('Carmen', ['Female', 'Basketball'])]
```